# SQL Server 2017 Error 26: Cannot connect to sql from other workstations

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-2017

I have a weird situation with one company that cannot connect to the SQL server through my application and keeps getting an error 26.

Remote connections are enabled in SQL server.
User Name and password are correct.
SQL Browser is running.
TCP/IP and Named Pipes protocols are enabled.
Static port is set and port is opened in firewall.
Default SQL ports are also opened in the firewall.
Telnet to both IP, port and name, port works.
Application works/connects on the SQL box itself.

Here's where it gets weird.

The company IS on a domain and has a server. (Windows SBS2012 that will eventually be decommissioned.) The SQL box is a workstation on the domain. Other boxes can access files on the SQL box with no problems. The application runs fine from the SQL box itself and connects beautifully. :) But no matter what type of connection I am trying, the other workstations keep getting an error 26. (This is happening on all workstations that try and connect.)

I have tried connecting using name\instance, ip\instance, tcp: with port, and a few other iterations.

There are no errors in the SQL log, and SQL log indicates that it is listening on the correct port.

I am at a total loss. Any brilliant ideas on other troubleshooting I can try?

Comment: Use a backslash instead of forward slash for the instance name. When you specify a port number, you don't need the instance name at all.

Comment: Has the SQL Browser service been restarted since you last reconfigured the SQL Server instance's protocols? Is udp/1434 accessible through software/hardware firewalls? When using instance names in connection strings the client first connects to udp/1434 and uses the SQL Server Resolution Protocol to map the name to the TCP port that the instance is listening on. It then makes a connection to the resolved TCP port to execute SQL queries. If you know which TCP port the instance is listening on then just use the port in the connection string, e.g.: `Server=tcp:ServerNameOrIpAddress,PortNumber;`

Comment: DanGuzman - Sorry. Clearly hadn't had enough coffee this morning. :)

AlwaysLearning - Restarted several times. And that was one of the many, many iterations that I tried.